# Removed main commit in github repo

Tags: git

Help guys, I just did a git reset on my main commit in a git repo, now the whole project has gone back to the start?

When i do git reflog i can see my previous commits still, how can i move to one of them and restart from there.

Anyway, I can recover this? Major error

Comment: Is everything in github? Whatever you do, don't push your mistake to github. You can attempt to fetch and checkout from origin.

Comment: no nothing on github yet its all within vs code, i think the head has also become detached somewhere

Comment: _"how can i move to one of them"_ You can `git checkout <commit hash>`

Answer (score 2):

Create a new branch, check it out and then reset it to the commit you see in the reflog:

```
git branch recover
git checkout recover
git reset --hard <commit-from-reflog>
```

This should give you the state you had at that point, including in the working directory.

Comment: You can use `git checkout -b recover` in order to create and checkout the branch in one step.

Comment: @dan1st Yeah, I avoid shortcut options in SO answers since they are way less clear for newcomers, specially in their short form.